# Vote Buttons Show Up on Locked Posts

Tags: bug, voting, locked-questions

I have found a bug with the vote buttons on this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
[image]

If the post cannot be voted on, why are there vote buttons? I also noticed that all answers except the first one *can* be voted on.

Comment: *Basically*, this goes back to [something Joel said a long time ago](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html). But it's been brought up repeatedly with little results.

Comment: This isn't a bug AFAIK. I'm not a web developer, but I'm guessing extra programming (and testing) would be needed to remove the vote buttons. You might make a feature request to remove the buttons and the error message with it if you think there's a real problem worth pursuing here...but it probably comes down to a choice of [tag:status-bydesign] vs. [tag:status-declined], because the error message pretty much says it all.

Comment: While I agree with Joel that disabled things shouldn't be hidden, they also should not look the same as enabled ones. Fade them out or something, just like the add comment link when you can't comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were down-voted, it *is* good UX to show buttons that won't work in some kind of a disabled state (or, not at all). But ... this *is* (unfortunately or not) consistent with lots of other areas that we show things people can't use (comments, etc).

I'm *not* going to mark this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because it's more [status-letsbeconsistentatleast](/questions/tagged/status-letsbeconsistentatleast) - but a fix for this is going to need to encompass *every* area where we show that particular modal on click instead of showing what you clicked in some kind of disabled state.

That's kind of hard to do with links that simply fire ajax requests only to have the endpoint say 'nope, not allowed'. We don't want to *not* show those, because we want people to see that the functionality *could* be there for them - getting that right is rather difficult.

Locked questions are more or less the corner case in the grand scheme, this just behaves consistently with every other area we show the means to access a feature that is still locked.

Answer (score 3):

This must be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

AFIR, there are 4 types of locks

[**1) Historical lock:**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/1671639)

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is
>   not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do
>   not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This
>   question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

*Here the voting mechanism, edits and flags are completely removed throughout the entire Q & A.*

[**2) Community wiki lock:**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1671639)

> This question and answer are a collaborative effort: if you see
>   something that can be improved, edit it!

Here the voting and edit options are blocked for the *exact particular question.*  ***But still the answers can be voted/edited/flagged.***

```
I also noticed that all answers except the first one can be voted on.
```

For the above question, the reasons are

[**3) Off-topic comments lock**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1671639)
[**4) Dispute content lock**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1671639)

The above *locks is for particular question or answer,* in-order to prevent flooding of comments and edits.

So removing voting buttons for a **particular locked answer or question(2, 3 & 4)** is not good for UI perspective therefore the error is message shown.